# Error while adding Application Component in Worklight 6.1

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to create and add application components to WL 6.1 project

I am able to create the component from a WL Project as per steps given in http://goo.gl/eJ7Rq7

But when I am trying to add the same component back to some other WL Project as per steps given in http://goo.gl/U1Aipp, I dont find my component in the list of components.

I get the following message on **Add and Remove Application Components** Pop Up window

**No application components are available**
**Application components folder path can be set in - Preferences > Worklight > Templates and Components > Download Folder**

And also the console throws the following error
Component = Sample.wlc
Found component.wcp
Found Image
Problem while reading the File= C:\Users...\IBM\templates\Sample.wlc

What might be the possibilities for the above error.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you have added additional hooks make sure they adhere to the structure given on the link [Additional hooks structure](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/studio_ext_assets/r_adding_hooks_to_application_component.html)

Table 1 lists the inner elements that are supported on Android and the order in which they must appear in your component.wcp

Table 1. Order of inner elements for the Android environment
Order   Inner element
1   CordovaPlugin
2   Activities
3   UserPermissions
4   Receivers
5   Strings
6   ExternalLibraries
7   Libraries

Table 2 lists the inner elements that are supported on iOS and the order in which they must appear in the schema.

Table 2. Order of inner elements for the iPhone and iPad environments
Order   Inner element
1   CordovaPlugin
2   Files
3   Libraries

Note: Some hooks result in the insertion of properties in the config.xml file or the AndroidManifest.xml file when the associated application component is added to a Worklight project. Every insertion is enclosed in comments that mention the element and application component unique name

Comment: Thanks for the reply...No I have not added any hooks yet. I just wanted to add a component into another WL Project to see how it works.

Comment: Please share the sample component.Was the component created using specific environment ? What were the set of files selected while exporting ?

Comment: I am trying to add a folder with some java files in it. Those files are not WL generated ones.

Comment: Are these external libraries which are required for the Android project ?